# How these game illustrations have grayer background?

Tags: illustration, games

As you can see in these images of a game the background colors are less saturated and grayer:

[image]
[image]

Do you think the designer reduced the transparency in the background or used grayer colors?

regards,

Saeed

Comment: It would seem a given that if colors vary, then there's been some change in value, hue or saturation. I really am not sure what you are asking, or what you are anticipating as an answer other than perhaps "Yes".

Comment: The backgrounds don't look less saturated to me. But a noticable difference if that the foreground uses black outlines but the backgrounds use different colored outlines.

Comment: Is this from a NewGrounds game? It looks like a NewGrounds game, haha

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the colours are greyer or less saturated in these examples. The backgrounds appear to be lower in contrast, but still pretty colourful. The foreground objects also have distinct outlines to separate them from the background.

Yes, most digital artists work with applications which support layers, so this is likely something done with layer opacities.

You could achieve something like the example by putting a layer filled with a solid colour between the background and foreground objects, then reduce the opacity of the filled layer to around 40% or so.  Here's an example using Photoshop, but almost any software that supports layers could be used similarly.

Here's a before and after with the colour fill layer switched on and off.

[image]